# Having trouble uploading file to Google Cloud Storage from Django(Local Windows ENV

Tags: python, django, django-forms, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently developing a web app that will use Google Cloud Storage for User Document uploads. I've run into a roadblock, however. When I attempt to proceed with the upload I keep getting a `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Marty McFly-Paycheck-06_ConditionalDirectives.pdf'`. This error is confusing to me because I assumed that the file would be taken directly from my form's file upload.

Am I wrong in assuming this? Should I be saving then serving the files somehow?

**Current Code for uploading documents to Cloud Storage**

```
    #Uploading Documents function
def upload_documents(bucket_name,source_file_name,destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    storage_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = storage_bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print("Document Uploaded")

from .forms import DocumentUpload
# Create your views here.
def get_upload(request):
    # If this is a POST request, we will process the data -- sending it to Google Cloud Storage

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #create a form instance populated with data -- (Bound to the data previously entered that might need correction)
        name = request.POST['name']
        titleofdocument = request.POST['titleofdocument']
        doc_file = request.POST['doc_file']
        fullUpload = name + "-" + titleofdocument + "-" + doc_file
        print(titleofdocument,name,doc_file)
        print(fullUpload)
        form = DocumentUpload(request.POST)
        upload_documents("upload_documents",fullUpload,"SampleBlob")

    else:
        form = DocumentUpload()

    return render(request, 'document-upload.html',{'form':form})
```

**Full Stack Trace in question**

```
Marty McFly-Paycheck-06_ConditionalDirectives.pdf
Internal Server Error: /upload-documents/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joel\Documents\dev-projects\django-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Joel\Documents\dev-projects\django-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Joel\Documents\dev-projects\django-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joel\Documents\dev-projects\greaterdemand\documents\views.py", line 40, in get_upload
    upload_documents("upload_documents",fullUpload,"SampleBlob")
  File "C:\Users\Joel\Documents\dev-projects\greaterdemand\documents\views.py", line 23, in upload_documents
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
  File "C:\Users\Joel\Documents\dev-projects\django-env\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\storage\blob.py", line 988, in upload_from_filename
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Marty McFly-Paycheck-06_ConditionalDirectives.pdf'
[20/Jan/2018 10:54:03] "POST /upload-documents/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78673
```

If anyone has any links to helpful documentation or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass the file. `form = DocumentUpload(request.POST)` should be `form = DocumentUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uploaded file is in `request.FILES`. You are not passing files to the form. Try this.

```
form = DocumentUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this may have placed me on the right path. One question, as I've never used `request.FILES` before. Is there a way to dynamically get the name of the file?